# GAPI, get unique visitors

Tags: php

how can I get all the unique visitor from the GAPI class.

```
$ga = new gapi(ga_email,ga_password);

$dimensions = array('visitCount');
$metrics    = array('visitors');


$ga->requestReportData(ga_profile_id, $dimensions,$metrics);

$gaResults = $ga->getResults();


//print_r( $gaResults);




$i=1;

foreach($gaResults as $result)
{

   $total= $total+ $result->getvisitors() ;
         //  $result->getVisitors()


          // );


 // print_r($result);
}

echo $total;
```

Comment: Nothing that is of help to you here: http://code.google.com/p/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface/?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ga->requestReportData(ga_profile_id, array('pagePath'), array('visitors'));
foreach($ga->getResults() as $result) {
    var_dump($result);
}
```

If you check https://developers.google.com/analytics/community/export_changelog for log of Release 2011-01 (January 24, 2011).

> The calculation of ga:visitors has been changed to return the number
>   of unique visitors across the date range and now supports more
>   dimension and metric combinations.

Comment: Thanks, but unique page view is not the same as unique visitor ..... cause my unique visitor is way less then the unique pageview.